# Can I find ode23, ode45, and ode113 solvers in Scilab?

Tags: ode, scilab

Can I find ode solvers (ode23, ode45, and ode113) in Scilab?
I use these solvers in MATLAB, but I have no idea if there is the same option in Scilab or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to expand the question with more details or a follow-up (that is not a new question on its own), please edit the question text. Try to be as minimal as possible, mark additions as such. But debug first, question expectations like "does the exact solution really belong to the differential equation" or "is the format of automatically generated objects like from `linspace` really like expected a column vector"?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the search function? The answer in [Convert ode45() to scilab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70978145/convert-ode45-to-scilab) should give an idea, even if RKF is not DoPri5.

Read the documentation on the other available steppers.

- The default stepper without type parameter uses lsoda, which can be seen as comparable to ode113
- With "stiff" you get lsode, which is approximately equivalent to ode15s.
- "adams" could substitute for ode23, there are no explicit low-order methods available, so adaptive-step and order Adams-Bashford is the best you get for a fast integration. And, as mentioned,
- "rkf" is an embedded explicit 4(5) method that can substitute for the embedded explicit (4)5 Dormand-Prince method of ode45.

There exist more modern solvers and step-size heuristics, using dense output, an advanced event "root->action" mechanism etc. Scilab is not alone in having a stalled development in this regard. The default is good enough for small projects and prototyping, for massive number-crunching use a compiled language.

Comment: "stiff" is rather equivalent to ode15s as it uses lsode, hence BDF with maximal order 5. The "rkf" option leads to classical Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg, but the adaptation formula is very basic. In any case, ode() with default option (using lsoda)  is a good swiss knife (with automatic stiffness detection).

Comment: Thank you. The existing (online) documentation both on the scilab side and for odepack is rather condensed, lacking in details. On lsoda-lsode they appear to hold opposite viewpoints on the usability for stiff problems.

Comment: odepack is quite obsolete compared to the Sundials suite. Hopefully the latter will be available in next Scilab version.